# Is endoderm visible in the germ layer?

Tags: embryology

This picture is my drawing about germ layer - not embryonic folding as I wrote initially.

[image]

**Where exactly is the endoderm here in the picture?**

The known things

1. Ectoderm
2. Neural tube
3. Notochord
4. Endoderm - **Where is this?**
5. Somite
6. Somite leg
7. Intraembryonic coelom
8. Embryonic somatopleura
9. Embryonic splanchopleura (lateral mesoderm)
10. Endoderm
11. Mesoderm (intraembryonic)

Comment: Ok so that's not the best picture, but I think it would be along the bottom of the top wall there.  Want to give us a few clues with the parts you're sure of?

Comment: Another strong possibility is that you're missing it in the inside of 2.

Comment: @AtlLED I added clues to the body of the question.

Comment: umm... you do note you have endoderm twice, once as 10...

Comment: Again you may or may not want to further clarify what slice and when in the germ layer you are looking (might make this a better question). After thinking about it, I think you were going for neural tube and chorda formation (which is exactly what I DDG'ed to pull that image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going for a view of tube formation, in which case, here's a good image:

[image]

1. Lateral plate mesoderm
2. Intermediate mesoderm
3. Somite mesoderm
4. Chorda
5. Endoderm

   [(Reference)](http://www.vcbio.science.ru.nl/en/virtuallessons/embryology/chicken-33-36h/)

Again in your drawing I think you correctly have it labeled as 10, and don't really need to put it twice.

Comment: Thank you! Of course, I had mistake in numbering and then started to think where the missing number should be, since all known parts were already taken.